# Want To Know More About Undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined

As you see,undefined is not a keyword in javascript(Is it right?).So we can use it as a variable though I'm sure this is a bad idea.Now my question is why I can't give a value to undefined.

Code:

```
var undefined=3;

undefined;//still undefined
```

Any suggestions will be thankfull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in older environments(before JS 1.8.5) it was possible to change the value of undefined, and checking for something that didn't exist was made in a way that was possible to break. It is a common choice to develop libraries inside their own closures, using the IIFE pattern to create a variable undefined which is not touched from external code(jQuery for example, and most libraries), this is an example:

```
(function(undefined) {
    //code which safely uses undefined
})();
```

Note that there is a parameter called `undefined` and the IIFE is invoked **without any parameter**, making that `undefined` effectively become `undefined`. In newer environments it is not possible to change the value of undefined, but for retrocompatibility it is yet used a lot.

Yet the safest way to check for an undefined type is to use `typeof`. Its usage, in fact, cannot be overridden in any way, and it can be used safely: `typeof foo == 'undefined'`.

Remember that there is a slight difference between **undefined** and **undeclared**:

```
var x; //declared but undefined
x === undefined; //true
```

But in older environments you were able to do

```
var undefined = 1;
var x; //declared, of type undefined, but...
x === undefined // false, because undefined is 1 and x is of type undefined
```

As I said before, the safest way to check for an undefined variable(being sure it will work in older environments) is to use typeof:

```
var undefined = 1;
var x;
typeof x == 'undefined'; //true
```

Remember also that using equality check(`==`) with `undefined` also checks for `null`(in fact, `undefined == null` but `undefined !== null`), so I recommend using strictly equality operator(`===`), which checks **only for** `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

See a full explanation (I'm not the author) of how 'undefined' is used in JavaScript here http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/16/understanding-undefined-and-preventing-referenceerrors/

> Compared to other languages, JavaScript’s concept of undefined is a
>   little confusing. In particular, trying to understand ReferenceErrors
>   (“x is not defined”) and how best to code against them can be
>   frustrating.
>
> In JavaScript there is Undefined (type), undefined (value) and
>   undefined (variable).
>
> Undefined (type) is a built-in JavaScript type.
>
> undefined (value) is a primitive and is the sole value of the
>   Undefined type. Any property that has not been assigned a value,
>   assumes the undefined value. (ECMA 4.3.9 and 4.3.10). A function
>   without a return statement, or a function with an empty return
>   statement returns undefined. The value of an unsupplied function
>   argument is undefined.
>
> undefined (variable) is a global property whose initial value is
>   undefined (value), Since its a global property we can also access it
>   as a variable.
>
> As of ECMA 3, its value can be reassigned :

```
undefined = "washing machine"; //assign a string to undefined (variable)
typeof undefined //"string"

f = undefined;
typeof f; //"string"
f; //"washing machine"
```

> Needless to say, re-assigning values to the undefined variable is very
>   bad practice, and in fact its not allowed by ECMA 5 (though amongst
>   the current set of full browser releases, only Safari enforces this).

Comment: Link-only answers are discourages because the resource can disappear over time. Please include the essential bits in your answer.

Comment: I understand, in this case though there is a lot of detail which the answer would be incomplete without, and I didn't want to just cut and paste a large section of that page. What do you recommend?

Comment: *As of ECMA 3, its [...] only Safari enforces this).* seems to be the relevant part you can quote, in addition to the link in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined), undefined became non-writable, starting in JavaScript 1.8.5.
That yields that it was fully "legal" to use it as a variable until then.
But it obviously isn't a good idea.